# Need Image with Sweref99_1800 projection/coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, image

I need third party image tiles (probably world imagery) under sweref99_1800 projection and coordinate system (EPSG 3008). I found this link http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-cross-blend-hypso/ 
for downloading world imagery but it is in spherical mercator projection (EPSG 4326). Is there any link from where we can download world imagery in sweref99_1800 format.

OR

is it possible to change the projection and coordinate system of image tiles (world imagery) from spherical mercator(EPSG 4326) to swereff99_1800 format (EPSG 3008) ?

Comment: Note 4326 is not a spherical mercator projection, it's unprojected lat/lon (or lon/lat).

Comment: Spherical mercator is defined as EPSG:3857 (and some other too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3006/) I can see that you'll need to clip your image to 10.5700, 55.2000, 24.1800, 69.1000 first then warp it. ([see the faq](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQRaster#HowdoIusegdal_translatetoextractorclipasub-sectionofaraster))

```
gdalwarp -projwin 10.5700 69.1000 24.1800 55.2000 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3008 yourfile.tif outfile.tif
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful information. As i understand, -projwin will extract a small window (a part of imagery)with 10.57, 55.200, 24.180, 69.100 bounding box from world imagery and then will change the projection/coordinate system to 3008. Am i write in my understanding ?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to project the image. You can do so by installing the [GDAL package](http://www.gdal.org/index.html) and using [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).

In your case, you would run this command

gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3008 yourfile.tif outfile.tif

You can play around with the various resampling methods (bilinear, cubic, cubicspline, lanczos) to see which produces the best results.

Comment: This will not work with a worldwide source file, because SWEREF like every transverse mercator projection will produce artefacts outside its area of definition.